# Importing XML to Objects Recursively

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to write a method which uses reflection in order to get the properties and set their values while traversing XElement:

Lets say I have a class like this which only provides me XML value to be parsed:

```
class XMLController
{
    public string XML
    {
        get{
            return @"<FieldGroup name='People' count='20'>
                <Fields>
                    <Field Name='Jon' LastName='McFly'/>
                    <Field Name='Michael' LastName='Jackson'/>
                </Fields>
            </FieldGroup>";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how my Objects look like:

```
class FieldGroup
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Count {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Field> Fields {get;set;}
}

class Field
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

The mapper method traverses `XElement` and since the Node names are matching names with the Objects I am thinking this helps little more but I haven't come up with something really useful. I don't want to pass the type but rather, the method will work with almost every XML  passed in with the same format.

All it knows the fact that the XML nodes and attributes are matching names.

This is what I've done but didn't really worked:

```
class XMLObjectMapper
{
    public T Map<T>(XElement element) where T: class, new()
    {
        T entity = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        if(element.HasAttributes)
        {
            MapXMLAttributesToObject<T>(element,entity);
        }
        if(element.HasElements)
        {
            foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())
            {
                //if the child element has child elements as well, we know this is a collection.
                if(childElement.HasElements)
                {
                    var property = GetProperty<T>(childElement.Name.LocalName);
                    property.SetValue(entity,new List<property.PropertyType>());
                    Map<T>(childElement);

                }
                else
                {
                    var property = GetProperty<T>(childElement.Name.LocalName);
                    var type = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
                    type.Dump();
                }
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }

    private void MapXMLAttributesToObject<T>(XElement element, T entity)
    {
        foreach(XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
        {
            var property = GetProperty<T>(attribute.Name.LocalName);
            property.SetValue(entity,attribute.Value);
        }
    }

    private PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName,BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: Not really gives the flexibility I need unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but as you've noticed, you've got some errors.

The following piece of code doesn't compile because you can't use a value (`property.PropertyType`) in place of a type name. C# is a statically typed language, so types have to be known at compile time rather than being in variables:

```
new List<property.PropertyType>()
```

However, if you use reflection, you can choose the types at runtime. We can do this instead:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(collectionElementType))
```

The other problem that you have is that you can't just call `Map<T>(childElement)`. First of all, T is not the right type -- it's the parent element's type, not the child's. Secondly, the child is actually a collection, and `Map<T>` doesn't know how to handle collections, only individual objects. We have to loop over the child elements, map onto each single one (calling `Map<T>` with the type of the elements in the collection -- in your example, `Map<Field`), and then add them all to the collection. I've made a new version of your `Map<T>` that works:

```
public T Map<T>(XElement element) where T : class, new()
{
    T entity = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    if (element.HasAttributes)
    {
        MapXMLAttributesToObject<T>(element, entity);
    }
    if (element.HasElements)
    {
        foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())
        {
            var property = GetProperty<T>(childElement.Name.LocalName);
            // If the child element has child elements as well, we know this is a collection.
            if (childElement.HasElements)
            {
                // Assume collections are of type IEnumerable<T> or List<T>
                var collectionElementType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                // var collectionValue = new List<collectionElementType>()
                var collectionValue = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(collectionElementType));
                foreach (var grandchildElement in childElement.Elements())
                {
                    // var collectionElement = this.Map<collectionElementType>(grandchildElement);
                    var collectionElement = this.GetType().GetMethod("Map").MakeGenericMethod(collectionElementType).Invoke(this, new object[] { grandchildElement });
                    collectionValue.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(collectionValue, new object[] { collectionElement });
                }
                property.SetValue(entity, collectionValue, null);
            }
            else
            {
                // I'm not sure what this should do -- this case doesn't happen in your example.
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
    return entity;
}
```

It certainly needs some more error handling, and I'm assuming you wanted to do something useful in the case where I threw a `NotImplementedException`. However, it works on your sample.